# CALL command prompt in SAP ABAP with command line

Tags: cmd, command-line, abap, sap-basis

is it possible to instead of opening a batchfile instead, it will go straight to command prompt with the command line "`cmd /c start "" http://www.stackoverflow.com`".

My current code still opens a batchfile locally instead:

```
DATA: lv_cmd TYPE string.
lv_cmd = 'C:\Users\James Francis\Desktop\TrackURL.bat'.

call function 'GUI_EXEC'
  exporting
    command          = lv_cmd.
```

batch file contains this:

```
start "" http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: Could you explain the reason for thinking that you need to run a batch file, cmd.exe and/or its built in `start` command, just to open a URL from  SAP ABAP? What is wrong with `FM CALL_BROWSER` for example?

Comment: Because the java features of the browser doesn't run in SAP lower in 770

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already got the answer

```
call function 'GUI_EXEC'
  exporting
    command          = 'cmd /c start "" http://www.stackoverflow.com'.
```